# Glean email address from site visitors

Tags: java, c#, email

My company wants to be able to match up a site visitor to their CRM contact list via the contacts email address used in the CRM.  They want to do this by capturing the email address of visitors to the website without the visitor having to provide it.  Is this even possible?

TIA

Comment: Hopefully not. I would throw out any browser that throws around my email address without me asking for it.

Comment: Nope.  The only way is to some pretty jerky things and piss people off if they find out.